# Deafult expiry time of JWT token

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

What is default expiry time of jwt token?

tried generating jwt token without mentioning expiry time.
but could not found the expiry time of the token.

```
function generateToken(payload) {
  return jwt.sign(payload, JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "1h" });
}
```

```
function generateToken(payload) {
  return jwt.sign(payload, JWT_SECRET);
}
```

I want to Implement strict logout functionality using JWT tokw. where user will be logged out only when either he/she logout manually or app new release.

Answer (score 0):

A JWT stays valid until it expires. You can't "make it expire". A JWT should not be used as a session replacement, [read here for more information](https://www.websecuritylens.org/common-jwt-implementation-mistakes-and-how-to-exploit-them/).

You can flush the users cookies (however having JWT in cookies is not good unless they are httpOnly). But this will keep the user logged in in other devices/browser sessions.

Regarding log out on new release: You could add a `version` key in the payload which you also would need to check when verifying the JWT.